# Spring Cloud Data Flow : Cannot run program "docker"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow

I want to deploy Spring Boot applications using Kinesis streams on Kubernetes cluster on AWS.

I used *kops* in an AWS EC2 (Amazon Linux) instance to create my cluster and deploy it using *terraform*.

I installed Spring Cloud Data Flow for Kubernetes using *Helm* chart. All my pods are up and running and I can access to the Spring Cloud Data Flow interface in order to register my dockerized apps. I am using ECR repositories to upload my Docker images.

When I want to deploy the stream (composed of a time-source and a log-sink), a big nice red error message pops up. I checked the log of the *Skipper* pod and I have the following error message starting with :

```
org.springframework.cloud.skipper.SkipperException: Could not install AppDeployRequest
```

and finishing with :

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/tmp/spring-cloud-deployer-5769885450333766520/time-log-kinesis-stream-1539963209716/time-log-kinesis-stream.log-sink-kinesis-app-v1"): error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
        at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.local.LocalAppDeployer$AppInstance.start(LocalAppDeployer.java:386) ~[spring-cloud-deployer-local-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.local.LocalAppDeployer$AppInstance.start(LocalAppDeployer.java:414) ~[spring-cloud-deployer-local-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.local.LocalAppDeployer$AppInstance.access$200(LocalAppDeployer.java:296) ~[spring-cloud-deployer-local-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.local.LocalAppDeployer.deploy(LocalAppDeployer.java:199) ~[spring-cloud-deployer-local-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.7.RELEASE]
        ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
        ... 58 common frames omitted
```

I already had this error when I tried to deploy on a local k8s cluster on Windows 10 and I thought it was linked to Win10 platform.

I am using `spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes` at version **1.6.2.RELEASE**.

I really do not have any clues why this error is appearing. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found where was the issue. My bad, the problem is always between the keyboard and the chair !

I wanted to remove all the metrics process in the `skipper-config.yaml` file and I inserted a typo in the configuration file. The JSON env variable `data.spring.application.json` for the Skipper launch was not valid hence the `DeployerInitializationService` never saw the properties it needed to add Kubernetes into the repository !

Now in the logs and in the dataflow shell I have the `default` and the `minikube` accounts. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the `docker` command is not found by the SCDF `local` deployer's ProcessBuilder when it tries to run the docker `exec` from this path:

/tmp/spring-cloud-deployer-5769885450333766520/time-log-kinesis-stream-1539963209716/time-log-kinesis-stream.log-sink-kinesis-app-v1

The SCDF sets the above path as its working directory before running the `docker` command and hence `docker` is expected to run from this location.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I am understand this correctly, the SCDF `local`deployer is used. I want to use the `Kubernetes`deployer.

In the Skipper documentation, it is written : 
`Skipper supports deploying to multiple platforms. The platforms included are Local, Cloud Foundry and Kubernetes.`

Hence I should be able to use the `Kubernetes`deployer. I check on the Helm chart that I am using and in the `values.yaml` file, there is a property : `skipper.platformName=minikube`. Is this ensure us to use the `Kubernetes`deployer ?

Comment: The `platformName` is the account named used in your configuration. For instance, you can configure your properties as mentioned here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-skipper/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#skipper-kubernetes-configuration

Comment: I saw that `yaml`configuration file in the documentation. As I am using Helm chart to deploy SCDF stack, I do not see where I can fill these properties except as application properties given in parameters. In the `skipper-config.yaml` file, there is a property : `spring.cloud.skipper.server.enableLocalPlatform` set to *false*. So my guess was that `Kubernetes`was automatically used.

Comment: You can check the configuration properties here: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/spring-cloud-data-flow. You can use `skipper.platformName` to override any custom k8s account. Otherwise, `minikube` is the default account name.

Comment: Alright. I think I am starting to see where the real issue is. I was not targetting the correct deployer using SCDF stream deployer interface ! I am still trying to figure out to specify the Kubernetes deployer. There is a global `Platform` property which matches with the `skipper.platformName` which has a `default (local)` value. If I try to put another value like "Kubernetes" or "minikube" (according to the configuration), the option is marked as *Invalid*. And there is a category `Deployment Platform`that I do not know what I can put into it.

Comment: And one more thing, when I am using the Helm chart to deploy SCDF on a Kubernetes cluster, when I check for the `platform-list` using the SCDF shell, I still have *default* platform even if I have the Skipper server `enableLocalPlatform` property set to _false_ !

Comment: The `default` platform would now point to the k8s account. Check the other env attributes for the platform from the `platform-list`